# Event is not firing after updating Android OS version 6.0.2

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have a video start and end event firing on video starting and completion. It is working fine until I updated to OS Version 6.0.2 on Samsung Galaxy S5.
It's working fine on chrome, firefox even on Iphone browsers but not on Android native browser

Code:

```
$(document.getElementById('movie')).on('fullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange webkitbeginfullscreen webkitendfullscreen', (
  function (e) {
       $(document).off('fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange');
       $scope.onFullScreenChange(e.type);
 }));


if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (videoElement.exitFullscreen) {
            videoElement.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (videoElement.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            videoElement.webkitExitFullScreen();
        } else if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
   }
```